# Set ANSI_PADDING on a specific column (ANSI_PADDING ON and OFF in different columns of the same table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

Is it possible - using a single CREATE TABLE script - to set specific `varbinary` columns `ANSI_PADDING = ON` but others to `ANSI_PADDING = OFF`?

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE PaddingX (
    ...
    ColumnA varbinary(max),
    ...    
    ColumnB varbinary(50)
)
```

I would like `ColumnA` to trim (padding `OFF`), but `ColumnB` to contain the full (padded) value - padding `ON`.

Comment: Why padding on a varbinary?

Comment: We store (fixed length) hash values which are then used to compare hashes created down the line.  Not padding the value results in mismatches, i.e. stored hash != padded differs from the current created hash that contains the padding (by default)

Comment: You seem to be determined to do this and you got your answer. But it seems like a far better approach to store the right data in the first place instead of using ANSI_PADDING as a hack to fix it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it in two steps:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
-- create the table without the columns that need ANSI padding
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
-- alter the table to add the columns that need ANSI padding
```

This is the only way to do it.

If you look at the remarks of [SET ANSI_PADDING docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx), you can read:

> This setting affects only the definition of new columns. After the column is created, SQL Server stores the values based on the setting when the column was created. Existing columns are not affected by a later change to this setting.

NOTE: for adding new columns, you can see the A Example of [ALTER TABLE docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx).

Comment: I agree that existing data will not be updated, but surely any new entries will be padded.

Comment: What existing data if in your question you say you're creating a new table? And, not surely not. it will work as I've told you.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to also work for a table with existing columns that need to be changed:

```
SET ANSI_PADDING ON 
GO 

ALTER TABLE [TableX] ALTER COLUMN [ColumnY] VARBINARY (50) NULL; 
GO 

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF 
GO
```

Any comments? It appears to solve the issue...

Comment: The only comment is that this is what I explained you in my answer. Why answering what is already answered? If my solution worked for you, as I can see it did, I beg you to accept it as correct answer.

Comment: You are right, my original question was answered by you - will mark it as such.  Part of my issue, which I didn't clarify in my question was how to set existing columns as well without recreating the table.

Comment: Even if this should be a separate question, I'll answer in a comment (we are not supposed to do this!): there is only one way of updating the existing columns: copy the data to a separate table, drop and recreate the table and copy the data back to the new table. This also requires recreating relations, indices, and other constraints: don't forget to do it.

Comment: I agree with you 100% - hence my comment earlier 
"I agree that existing data will not be updated, but surely any new entries will be padded"

The issue is probably more complex due to our current situation and I cannot share full detail, but the answers definitely helped sort out the specific problem.