# Stored procedure varchar output parameter

Tags: varchar, visual-studio, output-clause

Yesterday, I noticed something odd when returning a varchar(100) output parameter from my stored procedure in my asp.net application.  It appears that the returned value is now including the extra white spaces to return a full 100 characters.  This behavior is new.  The only thing I have changed recently is migrating the project from VS 2015 to 2017.  I am using System.Data.SQLClient to connect to the database.  Select statements for varchar columns return just the values in the columns and no extra white spaces.  Ansi_padding is off for the database and is not set any where in the code.

```
set @Message = 'Project Updated!' --where @Message is varchar(100)
```

This will return to the client.

```
_UpdateStatus = oData.outputParams.Item("@Message") 
_UpdateStatus = "Project Updated!                                                                                    "
```

Any ideas as to what is happening?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: What's the data type of the parameter in your .NET code? String or StringFixedLength? Please show us a bit more of your code

Comment: It would be better if database was mentioned too

Comment: Ansi paddings off are deprecated from SQL2016: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016

Comment: Sql server and using a string type in code. I did just end up adding a trim function to the class property for now. I will try  the debugging option mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solution:

```
_UpdateStatus = ((string)oData.outputParams.Item("@Message")).Trim()
```

Comment: To debug you can add the value of the property ANSI_PADDING in the stored procedure to the output to see what value it has when executing. For example like this: `set @Message = 'Project Updated ANSI_PADDING value used was=' + SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_PADDING')` I know that the .NET SqlClient sometimes sends its own default values for some of these properties (ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ARITHABORT etc) when setting up a connection

Comment: I will try this later. I was curious if .net was changing something. The database ansi padding is set to off.

Comment: "Project Updated ANSI_PADDING value used was=1                                                       " So does that mean it is ON?

Comment: Yes 1 means that `ANSI_PADDING` is `ON`. Try generating a script for the stored procedure by right clicking it in SQL Server Management Studio it will output the `ANSI_PADDING` that the stored procedure was generated with, it is a value that may be set individually per stored procedure and override the database default (which might "not" be a source of confusion ;) ) .

Comment: I tried setting ansi_padding to off, but it now gives me the following error:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235527/incorrect-set-options-error-when-building-database-project)

Comment: A column may be created with or without `ANSI_PADDING` it will affect how the column is stored. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28668954/set-ansi-padding-on-a-specific-column-ansi-padding-on-and-off-in-different-colu

Comment: In what context are you trying to `SET ANSI_PADDING OFF`? The stored procedure?